# Externarlize ehcache.xml to use properties from external properties file

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

I want to place property place holders in the ehcache.xml file (like ${}) so that the values can be replaced from external properties file (.properties) at runtime. 
Something like:

ehcache.xml (in classpath):

> ```
>  <defaultCache
> maxElementsInMemory="20000"
> eternal="false"
> timeToIdleSeconds="${default_TTI}"
> timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
> overflowToDisk="true"
> ... />
> ```

ehcache.properties (outside of the war/classpath):

> ```
> ...
> default_TTI=21600
> ...
> ```

The purpose is to be able to change the cache configuration without the need to rebuild the app. Spring's PropertyPlaceHolder will only work with Spring bean definiton for ehcache which I dont want (need to keep the ehcache.xml as a file)

There are similar posts here but nothing got me to solution. I've been searching for a week now!!

Im using Spring 2.5.6,Hibernate 3.2.6 and Ehcache 2.4.6

Any help or idea is greatly Appriciated!!

Thanks a lot,
Tripti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to [read the config in from disk](http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples#ways-of-loading-cache-configuration) at startup, you can do the following in EHCache 2.5:

```
InputStream fis = 
    new FileInputStream(new File("src/config/ehcache.xml").getAbsolutePath());
try 
{
  CacheManager manager = new CacheManager(fis);
} 
finally 
{
  fis.close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry pressed enter too early! I tried doing that too, but the problem is how to hook this CacheManager to hibernate? I have the following code in my hibernate context file:  `<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop><prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>`  So hibernate starts using the default ehcache.xml (available in the jar) and creates Caches using that instead of using the CacheManger I created.  Is there any way I can tell hibernate to use my CacheManager instead of creating the new one?  Thanks, Tripti.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaroud solution you can set property values to system scope (System.setProperty(...)). EhCahe uses these properties to resolve placeholders during parsing its configuration file.

Comment: Sadly ehcache incorporates only a simple property name replace, even in 3.8.0 . I mean that configurations in other systems allow to use many property names and even default value e.g. ${global.property,subsystem.property:100000} .

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution finally! Thanks to braveterry for pointing me in that direction.
I used this at context startup:

```
Inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("src/config/ehcache.xml").getAbsolutePath()); 
cacheManager = CacheManager.create(stream);
```

in conjuction with hibernate configuration:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
```

This creates a singleton CacheManager from ehcache.xml file outside the context classpath. I was doing this same earlier but was accidently creating another CacheManager before this one using the default ehcache.xml in the classpath.

Thanks,
Tripti.

Answer (score 1):

svaor， I follow what you mean， I define a bean like this：

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setProperty" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>system.project_name</value>
                <value>${system.project_name}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

system.project_name define in system.properties file which locate in classpath

I also create a ehcache.xml in classpath， in ehcache.xml has the code like this：

```
<diskStore path="${java.io.tmpdir}/${system.project_name}/cache" />
```

but when I deploy my project， I find it cann't use the system.project_name define in system.properties， why？